# Какие знаки препинания поставить в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

Точно так же и у тебя должен быть план (:) (,) без плана ты ничего не достигнешь (-) (:) (.) четкий план реализации своего успеха, реализации своей цели.

Comment: Мария, на сайте принято отмечать полезные ответы стрелочкой вверх и принимать самый для Вас подходящий галочкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

***Точно так же и у тебя должен быть план (без плана ты ничего не достигнешь) — четкий план реализации своего успеха, реализации своей цели.***

Answer (score 3):

***Точно так же и у тебя должен быть план - без плана ты ничего не достигнешь, - четкий план реализации своего успеха, реализации своей цели.***

Это предложение содержит **вставную конструкцию** ***без плана ты ничего не достигнешь*,** которую нужно выделить двумя **тире**.

**Запятая** разделяет повторяющиеся слова ***план*** и ***чёткий план***.

Ср.:  ***Тишина, глубокая тишина воцарилась вокруг.***

Comment: Согласна, не очень красиво звучит. Но не я автор данного предложения, соответственно, необходимо его написать таким, какое оно есть, с тремя словами "план". Иначе, я бы написала его по-другому и не стала бы так заморачиваться со знаками препинания и просить помощи.

Comment: Екатерина, спасибо!)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы внесла в предложение два изменения:
перенесла прилагательное "чёткий" к первому "плану" (в этом случае часть предложения после тире поясняет, раскрывает то, в чем эта четкость состоит);
заменила бы второй план (*без плана*) на местоимение (*без **него*** или *без **которого***).

Получилось:

*Точно так же и у тебя должен быть **чёткий план**, без **него** ты ничего не достигнешь, — **план** реализации своего успеха, реализации своей цели.*

Я ориентировалась на одно из правил постановки тире и на предложение Л. Толстого.
Тире может использоваться как дополнительный знак препинания после запятой в предложениях, где есть два повторяющихся слова, причем нужно это повторения для того, чтобы связать одну часть этого предложения с другой. Например:
*Теперь же, судебным следователем, Иван Ильич чувствовал, что **все без исключения**, самые важные, самодовольные люди, — **все** у него в руках.*

[Когда ставится тире](http://gramatik.ru/kogda-stavitsya-tire/)

**Дополнение** (после комментария)
Если предложение изменить невозможно, есть еще вариант (кроме уже указанных). Можно главный акцент сделать именно на вставке — с помощью восклицательного знака.

Точно так же и у тебя должен быть план — без плана ты ничего не достигнешь! — четкий план реализации своего успеха, реализации своей цели.

Comment: Римма, а мне нравится ваш вариант.  При повторе слов действительно ставится запятая и тире (тогда мы и повтор  как бы нормируем). Разделение двух определений также кажется убедительным.  Это всё касается семантики, но и структура предложения тоже улучшилась.  Голосую за вас.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, _Sharon._ Мне приятна ваша похвала.

Comment: Спасибо. Я бы, конечно, и сама догадалась изменить предложение, чтобы оно звучало более корректно. Но, как я уже написала выше, сделать этого не могу. Это же логично, если есть проблема в расстановке знаков препинания, то проще скорректировать само предложение и всё встанет на свои места. Но если человек просит помощи в конкретном данном предложении, значит других вариантов нет).

Answer (score 1):

Возможен такой вариант:

*Точно так же и у тебя должен быть план, без этого ты ничего не достигнешь — **четкий план реализации своего успеха, реализации своей цели.***

Комментарий

1) Это БСП. Между  предложениями  1 и 2 ставим запятую, обозначая только распространение темы, но не причинно-следственные значения.

2) С помощью тире обособляем  присоединительный оборот со значением пояснения (какой именно план).

3) Повторить слово ***план*** можно два раза, но не три.

**Почему я выбрала такую структуру**

Сообщение разделено **на две части**. Первая мысль о том, что план должен быть, иначе успеха не достичь.

Во второй части отдельно дается определение плана (каким он должен быть), и это уже вторая мысль.

Как мне кажется, такая (дискретная) подача информации более удобна для читателя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!)

Comment: А вашем варианте не нужна запятая после "не достигнешь" перед тире?